# Show legend for bar plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

How do I show legend for the following ggplot bar plot?

```
tmp <- data.frame(group = LETTERS[1:10], id = 10:1, a = runif(10), b = runif(10))

ggplot(tmp) + geom_bar(aes(x = reorder(group, id), a + b, group = 1), stat = 'identity')
```

Update: I have two charts arranged using `grid.arrange` from `gridExtra`. Both charts have the same number of bars, but one has legend. I thought that by adding any legend to the second chart, I will align the bars (make width of plot area of both plots the same):

```
tmp <- data.frame(group = LETTERS[1:10], id = 10:1, 
                  a = runif(10), b = runif(10), c = rnorm(10))

p1 <- ggplot(tmp) + geom_bar(aes(x = reorder(group, id), c, fill = a), stat = 'identity')
p2 <- ggplot(tmp) + geom_bar(aes(x = reorder(group, id), a + b, group = 1), stat = 'identity')

library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(p1, p2, heights = c(2, 1) )
```

Now, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: @MrFlick I oversimplified my problem, added more details.

Comment: Well, ggplot doesn't allow you to make up legends for things that aren't actually in the plot. The easiest thing would just to be to add `fill = a` for the second plot as well.

Comment: ...or you could move the first legend to the top or bottom of the first plot.

Comment: Maybe, check out: [Share a legend between two ggplot2 graphs](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this for p2, which will create a new legend for the bottom graph.

```
p2 <- ggplot(tmp) + geom_bar(aes(x = reorder(group, id), a + b, group = 1, fill = 0), stat = 'identity') +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Title"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i needed

```
 guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Title"))
```

Thanks