# ggplot2 single barchart legend doesnt appear

Tags: ggplot2, bar-chart, legend, legend-properties

I have a dataframe in the following format with 10 rows of data (listed below).
This is a list of obese children in Birmingham (England) by districts.

I am plotting this data in a barchart using ggplot2. 
On the X-Axis i have the district names
       y-Axis has the obese rate

the data bars show the obese rate in each district.

I have also added a benchmark line to compare Birminghams data against the districts. I have also plotted the upper and lower confidence intervals.

My Problem is-

How do i display the legends for this barchart? I belive because it is a single data item that the legends are not turning on? how do i turn on the legends?

I have changed geom_bar (show.legend = TRUE) but still i am unable to view the legends for this bar chart.

I would be most grateful for any help on this. 
Best Wishes MD from a sunny Birmingham.

COLUMN NAMES
*Districts*   (Names of districts)
*Obese*       (rates of obese)
*LL*          (Lower CI)
*UL*          (Upper CI)
*Birmingham*  (Cities obese rates for comparing)

(10 rows of data in total)

Answer (score 1):

The following question seems related to your question: [Show legend for bar plot in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098695/show-legend-for-bar-plot-in-ggplot)

Generally, a legend is shown when you use a fill, which you do not use.